# Angel.co API for IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios4

I am trying to connect to the angel.co API using IOS/objective-c?

But I do not know how to start.

Can anyone please help me?

How do I integrate the angel.co API in IOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what that API is, but assuming it is a web site, what you usually have to do is send GET, POST, PUT or DELETE HTTP requests. To do that, set up an NSURLRequest with that HTTP method, URL, and optionally filling in body data, then hand it to NSURLConnection to send that request off to the server and give you the return data.

To do that correctly, you'll have to get some API documentation from whatever web server you're talking to, or if you can't find any (i.e. they provide no API), you could view the source of their web pages using "View Source" in your browser and reverse-engineer the requests by looking at form fields, link URLs etc.